# how to test a deep learning model in a new dataset

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have train and test a model. Lets name it `model1`.

Now I want to test `model1` on a new dataset.
So I am saving the model with `H5` and then I load the saved `model1` in a new notebook and I test it with the new dataset.

Am I doing the procedure right?

When should I save `model1`? 
I see two options.

1. After training procedure.
2. After test procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there are many ways to design the training scheme of your model, a typical rundown might look as follows:

- Train your model using training data
- Use a validation set at the end of each training cycle or epoch
- Test your model's performance using a test set

Note that the model never sees the test set until the training and validation step is complete. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_validation,_and_test_sets) has an article devoted to this topic.

At which point you save your model is entirely up to you. In fact, you can make Keras or TensorFlow save the model at regular intervals during the training cycle, using certain [callbacks](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint). In short, there is no rule of thumb as to when you should save your model---it really depends on your goal. But as far as I can tell from your description, everything seems right: you have trained your model, saved it, and loaded it in a separate Jupyter Notebook to test it.

Just note that you could have tested the model within the same notebook you created and tested the initial model. You can also continue training the loaded model on the new notebook if you so wish.

Comment: Thank you JST99. i am running a human activity recognition problem. when i train and test model1 and then test it again with a new dataset the performance is superb. But when I only train model1 without test then save it and then load and test it a new dataset the perform is very bad. so i think that the decision you make on the initial model (model1 here) has to do with the performance on a new dataset

Comment: but as far there is no rule of thumb about the saving I think for my problem here is the best option is to train test save model 1 load model 1 in a new jupyter and then test it again with the new dataset

Comment: Glad it helped. Whatever works best in your situation should be the go-to solution. I'd just add a bit more and also say that it's always a good idea to have a validation scheme when you call `model.fit` so that you can monitor the performance of your model as it goes through training. Then, you can use a test set to call something like `model.evaluate` and make a final assessment of your model.